# Get data from multiple tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

Table 1 :- tbl_contacts

Fields

```
user_id

contact_id

first_name

last_name
```

Table 2 :- tbl_phone_details

Fields

```
contact_id

phone_number

phone_type
```

Table 3 :- tbl_email_details

Fields

```
contact_id

email_address

email_type
```

QUERY -

```
SELECT 
       tbl_contacts.*, tbl_email_details.*, tbl_phone_details.* 
FROM 
       tbl_contacts, tbl_email_details, 
       tbl_phone_details 
WHERE 
       tbl_contacts.user_id = '1'
```

I want to get first_name, last_name, Phone and Email details of particular user_id. I have used above query but its giving me repeated results and I am having less knowledge on DB queries like JOIN and INNER QUERY.

If anyone has any idea, please kindly help.

OUTPUT NEEDED:-

contact_id, first_name, last_name, phone_number, phone_type, email_address, email_type 
   (Here email and phone number can have 1 or more values for particular users).

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

> If you want to retrieve data for particular ID

```
SELECT T.contact_id, 
       T.first_name, 
       T.last_name, 
       P.phone_number, 
       P.phone_type, 
       E.email_address,   
       E.email_type
FROM tbl_contacts T LEFT JOIN tbl_phone_details P ON
                  T.contact_id = P.contact_id
                    LEFT JOIN tbl_email_details E ON
                  T.contact_id = E.contact_id 
WHERE  T.contact_id = @contact_id
```

> If you want to retrieve all data

```
 SELECT T.contact_id, 
       T.first_name, 
       T.last_name, 
       P.phone_number, 
       P.phone_type, 
       E.email_address,   
       E.email_type
FROM tbl_contacts T LEFT JOIN tbl_phone_details P ON
                  T.contact_id = P.contact_id
                    LEFT JOIN tbl_email_details E ON
                  T.contact_id = E.contact_id
```

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT tbl_contacts.*, tbl_email_details.*, tbl_phone_details.* FROM
>   tbl_contacts, tbl_email_details, tbl_phone_details WHERE
>   tbl_contacts.user_id = '1'

You forgot to mention the condition by which you are going to join all the tables!

```
SELECT c.first_name, c.last_name, p.phone_number, e.email_address 
FROM tbl_contacts c, tbl_email_details e, tbl_phone_details p 
WHERE tbl_contacts.user_id = '1' 
AND c.contact_id = e.contact_id
AND e.contact_id = p.contact_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how I would make that request with JOIN ... but there might be some better or faster way to do it.

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, phone_number, email_address 
FROM tbl_contacts 
JOIN tbl_phone_details 
    ON tbl_contacts.contact_id=tbl_phone_details.contact_id 
JOIN tbl_email_details 
    ON tbl_email_details.contact_id=tbl_contacts.contact_id 
WHERE tbl_contacts.user_id = '1';
```

And just so you don't get lost in all the different answers here (which are probably all correct):

- you don't need to give an aliase name to your tables (it's just for readability)
- you don't need to mention the table names in your column list if the column name is unique (e.g first_name is only in tbl_contacts). Just if you want the `contact_id` then you should decide which one (e.g. tbl_phone_details.contact_id)
- the multi-select as Jayaram proposed, is exactly the same as the JOIN. MySQL handles both queries the same way (I just didn't see his answer when I responded, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.contact_id, c.first_name, c.last_name,
     phone.phone_number, phone.phone_type,
     email.email_address, email.email_type
FROM tbl_contacts c
    LEFT JOIN tbl_email_details email ON c.contact_id = email.contact_id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_phone_details phone ON c.contact_id = phone.contact_id
WHERE tbl_contacts.user_id = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sql queries are easy to learn and write and they are very useful in getting the important data from database. `Joins` are used to basically fetch the data from two or more tables on the bases of common column in both tables.
`Inner Join` will select those values that are common in both of the tables.
`Left Join` will select all the data from the left table and `Right Join` will select all the data from right table on the basis of id.
These are the basics of SQL and you must know how to fetch accurate data using them.